# Find the inverse function $x + \sqrt {x}$

Tags: functions

$ Y = x + \sqrt {x} $

Hello , I want to find the inverse function of this function , I know that it's injective [How to prove the $f(x) = \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x}}$ is injective.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567599/how-to-prove-the-fx-sqrtx-sqrtx-is-injective) but do not know how to make the inverse function step by step.

Comment: Note that $x\ge 0$. Let $x=t^2$. You will then solve a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $y$, you need to find $x\ge0$ such that $y=x+\sqrt{x}$ or
$$
y-x=\sqrt{x}
$$
A necessary condition is $(y-x)^2=x$, which becomes
$$
y^2-2xy+x^2=x
$$
or
$$
x^2-(2y+1)x+y^2=0
$$
Can you find $x$ from this? Which one of the two solutions have you to consider?

Note that the condition $y-x=\sqrt{x}$ implies $y\ge x$, so the solution you must choose is the only one that satisfies $y\ge x$.

> Since you know that the function is injective, only one solution is acceptable; the two roots are $x_1=\dfrac{2y+1+\sqrt{4y+1}}{2}$ and $x_2=\dfrac{2y+1-\sqrt{4y+1}}{2}$. The first one is clearly greater than $y$, so we have $x=\dfrac{2y+1-\sqrt{4y+1}}{2}$, which is acceptable only for $y\ge0$. Indeed from $\dfrac{2y+1-\sqrt{4y+1}}{2}\le y$ we get $2y+1-\sqrt{4y+1}\le 2y$ or $1\le\sqrt{4y+1}$. So the inverse function is $y\mapsto \dfrac{2y+1-\sqrt{4y+1}}{2}$, defined for $y\ge0$.

Comment: :@egreg - Can YOU find x from this? Which one of the two solutions have YOU to consider?

Comment: @Ali.E. Yes, of course I can and of course I know which one of the solutions I have to consider. Since the question is clearly homework, I don't give the complete solution, but just some hints. Solving a quadratic shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Ali.E. There is another condition: that $y\ge x$, which is implicit in $y-x=\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: I think it might be easier to solve for $\sqrt{x}$ in the original equation then eliminate the negative root

Comment: @Dylan That's surely possible.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the @egreg 's answer I found an easier solution :

add $ +\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4}$ we have :
$$y = x + \sqrt{x}  +\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4}$$
then :
$$y=(\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}$$
$\sqrt{x} + \frac{1}{2}$ is clearly positive so :
$$(\sqrt{y+{\frac{1}{4}}}-\frac{1}{2})^2=x$$
then : 
$$x = y + \frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{y+{\frac{1}{4}}}$$
you can swap x and y to have the inverse function.

> Because the range of the function is $y ≥ 0$ we have $x ≥ 0$ for the inverse function domain.

Which is equal to this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1116697/208741

Answer (score 1):

This is basically Andrés comment elaborated:

Note that $f = g \circ h$ where $g(x) = x^2+x, h(x) = \sqrt x$, both $g,h$ are invertible on $[0,\infty)$.

Then $f^{-1} = h^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$.

Computing $h^{-1}$ is straightforward, computing $g^{-1}$ involves solving a quadratic.

Answer (score 0):

To make this easier, let $t = \sqrt{x}$ with the condition $t \ge 0$. Then we get

$$y = t^2 + t $$

or

$$ t^2 + t - y = 0 $$

This is simply a quadratic equation in $t$ that you can solve. There are two roots, but you can only take the positive one. The solution is:

$$t = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{1+4y}}{2}$$

Then it just takes some algebra to find $x = t^2$